# Scanner is throwing NPE

Tags: java, arrays, input, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

My code is throwing an NPE‌ exception at line 27 and 32.

`(names[i] = myScanner.nextLine();) + 
(content[i] = myScanner.next();)`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  static int timesNames = 0;
  static String[] names;
  static String[] content = null;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many things ? ");
    timesNames = myScanner.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i <= timesNames; i++ ){
      int times = i + 1;

      if(times <= timesNames ){
        System.out.println("Thing Nr." + times);

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Name of the thing: ");
        names[i] = myScanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Desciption : ");
        content[i] = myScanner.next();

        try {
          File newTextFile = new File("P:/" + names[i] + ".txt");

          FileWriter myFilewriter = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
          myFilewriter.write(content[i]);
          myFilewriter.close();

        } catch (IOException iox) {
          iox.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

What is causing this? Am I missing something?
I've searched about my problem but I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: `static String[] content = null;`

Comment: you did not initialize the names and content arrays

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
static String[] names;
static String[] content = null;
```

Both of those are initialized to `null` - one explicitly, one implicitly.  You need to set some default size on them.

```
static String[] names = new String[timesNames];
static String[] content = new String[timesNames];
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `names` and `content` yet, so try:

```
names = new int[namesArraySize];
content = new String[contentArraySize];
```

where `namesArraySize` and `contentArraySize` should your sizes needed for your arrays (in your case it's probably `timesNames`).

You assigned `content` explicitly with `null` and `names` was set to `null` implicitly, so both are actually `null` when you try to access them by `names[i]` and `content[i]` (therefore the NPE).

If you don't know how many items there will be stored you should try a `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the array after you know how many "things" there are:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many things ? ");
    timesNames = myScanner.nextInt();

    names = new String[timesNames];
    content = new String[timesNames];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors. 
1. You didn't initialize the arrays
2.When you do you will probably give them the size of timeNames,which will give you a NPE inside your loop 
To fix this you should change the conditions from i<=timeNmaes to i